# How to generate 100s of Stored Procedure Script with "CREATE OR ALTER" Statement in Sql Server 2016 SP1

Tags: sql-server

I have more than 100 STORED PROCEDUREs and I have to create single script for all those stored procedure. But traditional way to check exists and create or alter script is tedious task. I come to know that in Sql Server 2016 SP1, "CREATE OR ALTER" statement can solve my problem. But I am looking for tool where I can select name of SP(s) and can generate single script for all Store Procedure.

Comment: In SSMS, Right-click the database, under the Tasks sub-menu choose Generate Scripts, select only Stored Procedures, choose your output destination, profit.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just list all SProcs in the DB?

```
SELECT ROUTINE_DEFINITION
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
WHERE ROUTINE_TYPE = 'PROCEDURE';
```